# getURLParameter idea and suggestion

Tags: jquery, regex

hi there can you help how to get the value of campaign.id.clickid using

```
function getURLParameter(e) {
   return decodeURI((new RegExp(e + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search) || [, null])[1])
}
```

Sample URL:

```
http://sample.com/?in=fsdfsdf:37378&x_source=VP57835:campaign.id.clickid
```

Comment: Where is the value?

Answer (score 0):

With the function you provide you can get the URL parameter.
So get the `x_source` value and split it on the double colon:

```js
function getURLParameter(e) {
   return decodeURI((new RegExp(e + "=(.+?)(&|$)").exec(location.search) || [, null])[1])
}

var urlParameter = getURLParameter( 'x_source' );
var val = urlParameter.split(':');

console.log( val[1] );
```